# Script to fetch data from a URL and point it to load itself to a S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been assigned with automating the task of fetching some files(csv/Excel) from certain websites and then loading them to S3. I would like to know if a script can be written in someway so that if you put the url and the s3 bucket path and run the script, the files would load onto S3; and if yes, how would I go about it?

Open to alternative solutions as well. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple bash script, or any other language of your choice. Below are the steps for bash script:

1. Download the csv file using curl or wget.
2. Upload using aws-cli tools, `aws s3 cp`

Make sure you have aws-cli installed on the machine where you will be running this script.

You may want to read more about [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and [AWS CLI S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) commands.